# How to add items from List<T> into Combo Box but not duplicates in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox, duplicates

In a WPF project I have a simple List called "items" containing the following:

```
EURUSD
EURUSD
NZDUSD
```

I want to populate a comboBox with unique instances of the above. So I wrote a foreach loop to go through the "items" members, and then a for loop to check whether a given member was already present within the combobox (so not to add duplicates). My code is:

```
private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var positionz in items)
    {

        if (items.Count == 0) return;
        int combocount = comboBox.Items.Count;
        if (combocount == 0)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(positionz.Symbol);
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < combocount; i++)
        {

            if (comboBox.Items[i].ToString() == positionz.Symbol)
            {
               label.Content=i + "Good "  + positionz.Symbol + " matches combo item " + comboBox.Items[i].ToString();
                continue;
            }
            else { comboBox.Items.Add(positionz.Symbol); }
            label_Copy.Content = i;
        }

    }
}
```

The label stuff is just me trying to catch at what point the mistake is. For same reason when it matches the duplicate and continues to the next "i", it still adds the symbol to the combobox.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something silly but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Delete all that  and use  proper XAML and DataBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside data binding and possible equality issues... `using System.Linq;` you could replace the complete `foreach` with just:

```
foreach (var symbol in items.Select(i => i.Symbol).Distinct())
{
    combobox.Items.Add(symbol);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot about System.Linq being able to handle List<T>'s better like that.

Comment: A CollectionViewSource is the better fit here,

Comment: @BenediktSchroeder I'm totally aware that this isn't an idiomatic WPF solution, showing that is out of scope here though... this is close enough to the original proposal and does what the OP wants.

Comment: It is taged with WPF!